# neo4j- connection refused

Tags: php, neo4j

Hola comunidad soy nuevo con Neo4j, estoy conectándome desde php, acabo de instalar el server de neo4j con la configuracion básica, trato de hacer una petición al servidor con este codigo:

```
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:password@localhost:7687')
    ->build();
$query = "MATCH (n:Person)-[:FOLLOWS]->(friend) RETURN n.name, collect(friend) as friends";
$result = $client->run($query);

foreach ($result->getRecords() as $record) {
    echo sprintf('Person name is : %s and has %d number of friends', $record->value('name'), count($record->value('friends'));
}
```

y obtengo el siguiente error: **cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 7474: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olvidé un detalle que es crucial, mi código php se estaba ejecutando desde un container de Docker, por tanto, la dirección para consumir el servidor de Neo4j no podía ser **localhost**, tenía que ser, **172.17.0.1**, ahora sí funciona bien, dejo esto aquí para que lo utilice otro que le pueda hacer falta.

Finalmente he creado un docker file para poner el contendor de php y el contenedor del Neo4j, aquí les dejo el docker file

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  neo4j:
      image: neo4j:3.3.4
      ports:
        - "7474:7474"
        - "7687:7687"
  app:
    image: silex:dev
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    links:
      - neo4j
    ports:
      - "7018:80"
```

De esta forma en el controlador puedo llamar al Neo4j de la siguiente manera(el usuario que utilizo es: **neo4j** y la contraseña: **1234567**):

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
                ->addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:1234567@neo4j:7687')
                ->build();
$query = "MATCH (n:Movie) RETURN n LIMIT 25";
$result = $client->run($query);
```